# Compare two multidimensional arrays and add the missings

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, compare

I have two arrays which product IDs storing as keys.

First array goes like :

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
    (
        [_sku] => 
        [_qty] => 1
    )
    [34] => Array
    (
        [_sku] => 
        [_qty] => 3
    )
    [23] => Array
    (
        [_sku] => 
        [_qty] => 1
    )
)
```

Second array goes like :

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
    (
        [_sku] => 
        [_qty] => 1
    )
    [54] => Array
    (
        [_sku] => 
        [_qty] => 1
    )
)
```

My first array is the logged in user's basket. Second is the same user's not logged in basket. When user logged in I have to compere these 2 arrays and add the missing keys to first array but if the same keys exists in two arrays I have to roundup the first array's _qty with second's _qty (like : [1] => _qty is 1 and second array has also 1 qty so make firsts qty = 2 ). or process what I want and create a third array also possible I guess.

How to achive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `foreach` should do the trick:

```
foreach ($second as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($first[$key])) {
        $first[$key]['_qty'] += $value['_qty'];
    } else {
        $first[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: you sir totally saved me. I can't accept your answer now but I will in 9 minutes :)